# Wordpress: How to get the Url of the Website

Tags: wordpress

I want a function which gets a url of the website. Similar to this one: `<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>` But instead takes me to the URL of the website, so I can use it to link my homepage to the home button.

If there is a better way of how to link the home button just let me know.

Ryan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use

`<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>`

Answer (score 5):

Use [`get_home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_home_url):

> The `get_home_url` template tag retrieves the home url for the current site. Returns the 'home' option with the appropriate protocol, 'https' if is_ssl() and 'http' otherwise. If scheme is 'http' or 'https', is_ssl() is overridden.

```
echo get_home_url();
```

Almost all other Wordpress environment info can be fetched through the [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) function.

Comment: When I use this: <?php get_home_url(); ?> for my homepage link, from another page, is stays at the same directory :/

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer but as an alternative method, you can use this:

```
<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for the site url from the [WordPress Codex][1]

```
$url = get_site_url();
    echo $url;


  [1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/
```