# Get site URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating hreflang link, but it is generating error.

```
function Add_hreflang(){    
    $current_url = home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $current_url . '" hreflang="pt-br" />';
}
```

URL appears as ./ not full path site.com/url-name-title/

Comment: do you work on your localhost?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress: How to get the Url of the Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567646/wordpress-how-to-get-the-url-of-the-website)

Comment: On localhost it works, but not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use home_url() for getting url of the website.

```
function Add_hreflang(){  
  global $wp;  
  $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));
 echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $current_url . '" hreflang="pt-br" />';
}
```

Comment: Did not work. Any page displays only the homepage with get_site_url (). The_permalink () command works, but it is not in href = "" it is popping out. site.com/url-test/<link rel="alternate" href="" hreflang="pt-br" />

Comment: I used get_the_permalink (), but it didn't work either. <link rel="alternate" href="./" hreflang="pt-br"/>

Comment: Your question title was to get site url which could comeup with get_site_url. I have edited the code. Hope this is what you need. @RalfK